# Is it possible to allow users to withdraw certain amount of tokens if we sign that transaction somehow?

Tags: solidity

Let's say I create a token. Supply is some determined amount. I distribute that token like Brave browser let's say. I want the user to withdraw that token to their address. How could I do it?

I am thinking if I could do something like `"{message: sendTokenToAddress(user_address_added_in_account), amount: amount, signature: signature}"` and somehow verify it in the contract, and if verification is successful, allow the withdrawal to take place.

The thing is I want people to have tokens in their addresses without sending it myself (because in that case I would need to pay gas).

Comment: What you're looking for is [Merkle Airdrop](https://medium.com/smartz-blog/merkle-airdrop-the-basics-9a0857fcc930).

Comment: @goodvibration Anything else?